# Detect Headphones Unplugged - Monotouch

Tags: iphone, ios, binding, xamarin.ios, audiotoolbox

Is there a way to detect if headphones are unplugged in Monotouch?  I am trying to look for the `AudioSessionAddPropertyListener` method but don't see it.  What this method ported over?

Here is Apple's docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Audio_Session_Interruption_States

If anyone wants to see the code for how to do this, you can do the following:

```
AudioSession.PropertyListener p = delegate(AudioSessionProperty prop, int size, IntPtr data) {

            NSDictionary propertyDictionary = new NSDictionary(data);

            if (propertyDictionary.ContainsKey(NSObject.FromObject("OutputDeviceDidChange_OldRoute")))
            {
                string oldRoute = propertyDictionary.ValueForKey(new NSString("OutputDeviceDidChange_OldRoute")).ToString();

                if (oldRoute == "Headphone")
                {
                    if (audioPlayer != null)
                    {
                        audioPlayer.Pause();    
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        AudioSession.AddListener(AudioSessionProperty.AudioRouteChange, p);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to detect if headphones are unplugged in Monotouch?

I'm not sure but...

> I am trying to look for the AudioSessionAddPropertyListener method but don't see it. What this method ported over?

The native call to `AudioSessionAddPropertyListener` maps to MonoTouch's [`AudioSession.AddListener`](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=M%3aMonoTouch.AudioToolbox.AudioSession.AddListener%28MonoTouch.AudioToolbox.AudioSessionProperty,MonoTouch.AudioToolbox.AudioSession.PropertyListener%29) static method.

Comment: Excellent.  That is what I needed.  Is there a spot you looked to see how the API is mapped (between MonoTouch and the native call)?

Comment: Miguel's rosetta stone http://tirania.org/tmp/rosetta.html is the best resource when dealing with (Objective-C) selectors but it does not currently shows the pinvokes to C libraries. In general the bindings keeps the naming similar enough that MonoDevelop IDE autocompletion should suggest you likely candidates.